# Apple Store Review Team Rejected Build Because They Tested the Wrong Version

Tags: app-store, app-store-connect

I had a build of mine in the ios store get rejected. I forgot to replace the build that I wanted to submit to the app store. I went ahead and removed that build from my submission, and then put my current build in it instead and re-submitted that. However, they rejected it a second time and posted a screenshot showing the app and it was clearly a screenshot from my previous build that I initially submitted to them that was rejected, not the newer build where the issue they rejected me for wasn't present.

I pulled down the same version I submitted on TestFlight and confirmed that I had indeed submitted the correct version. Why is it that the AppStoreConnect review team re-tested using a previous submission build and not the current one? Am I missing something?